# Can You Inherit from a Custom Form that Inherits a Normal Form

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I've been trying for the past few hours to solve a problem that I don't understand really what is wrong. I'm building a GUI system for a project that needs multiple forms that are almost the same, but not quite. I figured I have one class (as show below) that inherits a standard, run-of-the-mill form.

```
class GUIWindow : Form, IGUIWindow
{
    public GUIWindow() : base()
    {

    }

    public GUIWindow(string name) : base()
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

and a second class (below) that inherits the first class, so that any change I make to the base class, it would affect all sub-classes, and there will be four or so sub-classes.

```
class GUIWindowText : GUIWindow, IGUIWindow
{

    public GUIWindowText() : base() { }

    public GUIWindowText(string name) : base()
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

But if I look at the designer in visual studio (2017), I get this error:

```
Constructor on type 'LCARS.GUIWindow' not found.
```

Even though I do provide an empty constructor. So I must be missing something obvious but I don't know what.

**EDIT**

It does compile fine. I just can't see the designer

Comment: Does it compile without errors?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes it compiles, but I can't look at the designer

Comment: Try making both form classes `public` in addition to having public parameterless constructors, and make sure that each one calls its respective `InitializeComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Let Visual Studio create the inherited form: In your project right click in the Solution Explorer to open the context menu, Add > New Item > Inherited Form (in the Windows Forms section) and then click "Add". This opens a wizard that asks you for the base Form, choose `GUIWindow` and click OK. VS then sets up the derived form correctly.

Note: If you want to change controls existing the base form in the derived form (e.g. change their size or move them around), you must change their accessibility from `private` to `protected`.

Comment: That didn't work. It did create a class but I can't use the designer.

Comment: Did you create the base Form `GUIWindow` by inserting the new item "Windows Form" in VS? You need to do that, because you need the whole setup with the partial classes and the `InitalizeComponent` method. If you create the class manually this won't work. (I.e. let VS create both Forms.) You can still implement the interface in the automatically created Form afterwards.